# Does DB2 Visual Studio Add-In work with VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, db2, db2-connect

I have both VS2008 and VS2010 installed and then I installed DB2 with the VS Add-ins. Now the Add-ins show up just fine in VS2008 but they do not show up in VS2010.

So, does the DB2 Visual Studio Add-Ins work with VS2010?

Also VS2008 is VS2008 Shell (integrated mode).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do work with VS2010. You'll need the latest version: 9.7 fp4 or later i believe. IBM also has a forum for .Net stuff: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=467 See the [first thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=368836&tstart=0) in that forum which announces 2010 support.

Answer (score 0):

yes it does. You need to download latest visual studio add ins for IBM DB2 and install it.

You may find it at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878
Before accessing above path you will required to register yourself with IBM Web. Instructions will direct you.